# To develop custom curl functionality in drupal7

Tags: php, curl, drupal, drupal-7

I am newbie to drupal and trying to develop a custom module for curl functionality of php which will get the content of  page and will display the whole  content
as it is.I tried but it is not displaying the content below is the code that I have tried.

```
function mycurl_menu() {

 $items['mycurl'] = array(
     'title' => 'My curl demo',
     'page callback' => 'mycurl_curl',
     'access callback' => TRUE,
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
 return $items;
}

function mycurl_curl() {

 $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36";
 $postdata ="name=amit&pass=amit";
 $options = array(

     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
     CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
     CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
     CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
     CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
     CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
     CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
     CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
     CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
 );

 $url = "http://localhost/drupal_commerce/product";

 $ch      = curl_init( $url );
 curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
 $content = curl_exec( $ch );
 $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
 $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
 $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
 curl_close( $ch );

 $header['errno']   = $err;
 $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
 $header['content'] = $content;
 return $header;

}
```

Comment: Try to comment out all the code inside the page callback `mycurl_curl()` and just return a simple string

Comment: @MuhammadReda yes when I commented the lines in page callback it worked  it returns the string which I  entered but it is not working  for the curl functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return $header['content'] since the menu callback is no supposed to return an array, and check the permissions of the page you are fetching with curl so that is it available.

Comment: Tried using return header['content']; but it is returning access denied message.

Comment: Check that http://localhost/drupal_commerce/product is configured to let you access anonymously, maybe the Access Denied page you are seeing is from the site you are calling, not the hosting site itself.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel,It is not showing access denied message now but now content is not displaying only title of the menu i.e "My curl demo" is appearing on the page.

Comment: Could you update the post to match your current code?  Remember not to return an array from the menu callback. For the sake of separating the problem into parts, return a fixed string value, as Muhamed Reda suggested.

Comment: Thanks @ManuelAlejandro got the solution for my problem changed the view access permission to anonymous and return header['content'] as you suggested.Again,Thanks a lot .